# .NET Installation failed

Tags: .net, frameworks

I'm recently having real trouble with installing .NET 6.0 Desktop Runtime (v6.0.1).

Here are the logs if anyone needs it : `## https://pastebin.com/1rCGznyV ##`

Here is a screenshot (which is in french and I'm very sorry for that) of the error message popping up : https://prnt.sc/26db103

I did everything to install it properly with administrator rights and release write access on Windows & Temp folders but still nothing.

It would be an honor to be helped by stackoverflow's support/community !

Comment: Log link did not work

Comment: Give it a try now, I updated it